# Is there any benefit to buy 24 inch monitor over 21.5 inch monitor if resolution is same?

Tags: windows-7, display, lcd

If resolution is same for different sized monitor then is it wise to go for cheapest?

Is there any benefit to buy 24 inch monitor over 21.5 inch monitor if resolution is same?

[image: Dell Monitors]

Comment: Depends on how much viewing area you want. From 21.5" to 24", I personally would take the 24", but it again, depends on how much viewing area you want. The resolution is the same since they are all widescreen monitors.

Comment: I'm looking for new LCD for Web development and currently using 17.5 inch monitor.

Comment: Go for the 24" model

Comment: Actually the resolution isn't the same for the U2410. Also, when switching from old style 4:3 aspect ratio monitors to a new wide-screen ones, similar diagonal size measurements result in monitors much smaller height-wise than you might think. Pay attention to the separately specified height and width measurements of each screen when deciding.

Answer (score 1):

In the end both Monitors can show the same amount of information (i.e. the same amount of pixels).

IMHO using a bigger screen instead of a smaller one is just easier on the eyes. But it depends on how fit your eyes are, how far away you are sitting, etc, pp. Just remember: In the end everything (text!) will look a bit smaller on the smaller screen. This can be exausting if you use your screen for long periods of time.

Other factors are (especially for Web Development):
 * color fidelity
 * constrast and brightness
 * Sometimes two monitors of the same model are using different panels with different quality (i'm having this problem with two Acer 22" at work. Same model, different picture!)

Comment: They aren't the same, one is 1920x1080 and the other is 1920x1200